# tic tac toe using builder 6 aplications form

Tags: c++, c++builder, tic-tac-toe

i'm doing a tic tac toe game in builder 6 with dinamic buttons and i encounted a issue whit the function which alternates the X and 0 when i pressed a button.

```
void __fastcall show(TObject *Sender)
{
    v=1;
    if(v%2==1)
        btn->Caption="X";
    else
        btn->Caption="0";
    v++;
    btn->Enabled=false;
}


for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
     for(j=0;j<5;j++)
     {
         object[i][j] = new C;

         //object[i][j]->v=i;
         object[i][j]->btn = new TButton(this);
```

the apel looks like this :

```
    object[i][j]->btn->OnClick=object[i][j]->show;
    }
}
```

if i dont use `object[i][j]->v=i;` it shows me only X or 0

I want to know how can i make to show 0 after X and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check if the button is enabled also:

```
if(btn->Enabled==true)
{
    if(v%2==1)
    {...
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Cheers,
Beco.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `v=1` on every click, only do that once when the program starts (or when you begin a new game).